# HTML going back to original state after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have a button on my HTML page that uses javascript to load html into the current page. On the new loaded HTML there is form that can be filled out. When the user submits the form I use ajax to process it. Once the ajax processes the form and stores the information into a database I call a success function to change the current HTML within a div. The inner HTML changes for a split second but then the entire page reverts back to the original HTML state.

Here is the javascript that I use to submit the form

```
function myFunction() {
    var deck_name = document.getElementById("deck_name").value;
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'deckName=' + deck_name;
    if (deck_name == '') {
      alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } 
    else {
       // AJAX code to submit form.
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../API/deck_api.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function() {
                   document.getElementById('right-panel').innerHTML = loadPage('../HTML_files/edit_deck.html');
                }
       });
    }
    return false;
 }
```

This is what loadPage() does:

```
 function loadPage(href) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
```

How can I make it so when the ajax is a success it changes the content of `right-panel` and it keeps it that way instead of completely reverting to the original state of the HTML.

Comment: What does `edit_deck.html` contain?

Comment: 1. what does loadPage method do
2. Some code is missing, as this code appears perfectly right
3. After all, Why do u mix jQuery and javascript unneccesarily

Comment: It contains another form but the form isn't active as of now. I am just trying to load in the basic HTML to see if the code works, but it only stays for a split second.

Comment: can you share the `loadPage`

Comment: synchronous ajax request? Are you kidding me?

Comment: @TRGWII I am unaware of what synchronous ajax request means.

Comment: It is what your loadPage-function uses ([Synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request)) and it is terrible practice...

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var deck_name = document.getElementById("deck_name").value;
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'deckName=' + deck_name;
    if (deck_name == '') {
      alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } 
    else {
       // AJAX code to submit form.
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../API/deck_api.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function() {
                  $("#right-panel").html(span);
        }
       });
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but the page still reloads the original html after the ajax call ends.

Comment: Answers with zero explanation (where the reader has to guess what was changed) are not as good as answers that explain themselves.